# Pandas: Sum up rows by group

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to create two sums, one conditional on `date` and `type`, and one only conditional on `date`. Here's an excerpt of my data frame:

```
                             0             1             2             3  
date       type                                                            
2003-01-01 unemp  1.733275e+09  2.067889e+09  3.279421e+09  3.223396e+09   
2005-01-01 unemp  1.413758e+09  2.004171e+09  2.383106e+09  2.540857e+09   
2007-01-01 unemp  1.287548e+09  1.462072e+09  2.831217e+09  3.528558e+09   
2009-01-01 unemp  2.651480e+09  2.846055e+09  5.882084e+09  5.247459e+09   
2011-01-01 unemp  2.257016e+09  4.121532e+09  4.961291e+09  5.330930e+09   
2013-01-01 unemp  7.156784e+08  1.182770e+09  1.704251e+09  2.587171e+09   
2003-01-01 emp    6.012397e+09  9.692455e+09  2.288822e+10  3.215460e+10   
2005-01-01 emp    5.647393e+09  9.597211e+09  2.121828e+10  3.107219e+10   
2007-01-01 emp    4.617047e+09  8.030113e+09  2.005203e+10  2.755665e+10
```

Now, I tried

```
weightsDf.groupby(level=[0,1]).sum()
weightsDf.groupby(level=[0,1]).apply(lambda x: x.sum())
```

These all give me the sum *per column*, not the sum *over all columns*. For the case where I wanted to condition on both `type` and `date`, I can simply do

```
weightsDf.sum(axis=1)
```

But how do I proceed for the case where I want to condition on `date` only? Unlike when applied onto the data frame,

```
weightsDf.groupby(level=[0,1]).sum(axis=1)
```

does not accept the argument `axis`. I *could* unstack the data frame for the second level and then sum by row again, but that seems too complicated.

Comment: First sum the columns, and then by group? ``weightsDf.sum(axis=1).groupby(level=[0,1]).sum()`` Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the sum over the columns first, and then group:

```
weightsDf.sum(axis=1).groupby(level=[0,1]).sum()
```